# ADF: How to pass binary data to stored procedure in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

I reading binary data (jpeg image) using an api (Web Action) and i want to store it as varbinary or base64 in azure sql server.

**As it looks there is no way to base64 encode binary data using azure data factory. Is that correct?**

So i am trying to pass it as byte[] using a varbinary parameter. The parameter of the stored procedure looks like this:

```
@Photo varbinary(max) NULL
```

The parameter in the stored procedure action in ADF looks like this:

[image]

But this seems also not to work, because the pipeline is failing with this error:

> The value of the property 'Value' is invalid for the stored procedure parameter 'Photo'.

**Is it possible to store that image using that approach? And if not, how can this be achieved (using ADF and Stored Procuedure)?**

Comment: There is no such direct approach for this task but you can achieve achieve it programmatically (using C#). Will that be fine for you?

Comment: okay thanks. But no it's not fine using c# here.. Maybe there is a workaround with storing the images in azure blob storage first?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be safe, are you missing a '@' before the activity ?
Cant see it on the picture

Peace

Comment: Yes thats a bad screenshot. the @ is there..